# Javascript code to read a Array of Maps

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

Here is the jsp code embedded in Java Script:

```
//This object comes from Java code to Jsp Code.    
var msgs = [{name=rajasekhar, langId=en, bShow=true}, {name=sekhar, langId=de,bShow=false},{name=valli, langId=en, bShow=false}];


<script type="text/javascript">
var langSectState = new Array();

 <c:forEach var="msg" items="${msgs}">
    <c:set var="langId" value="${msg['langId']}"/>

    langSectState ["${langId}"] = ${msg['bShow']};  //JS

 </c:forEach>
</script>
```

MoreInfo: The above code It extracts langId, bShow from msgs and stores values in Array.

After my server configuration changes, This is not working fine. So, I have to change this code to full Java Script.

Can anyone suggest the equivalent code to this in Java Script

Comment: Why not use JSON encode? `var langSectState=${msgs_json}` where `msgs_json` is the json-encoded array of maps.

Comment: Hi @Jan Dvorak, Can u please explain it. How directly "msgs" can be converted into that form. How to encode msgs to msgs_json ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you really need to overwrite values in this array (for example, you have two objects with langId="en"). But your code looks like the following one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var msgs = [{name:"rajasekhar", langId:"en", bShow:true}, {name:"sekhar", langId:"de",bShow:false},{name:"valli", langId:"en", bShow:false}];
var langSectState = new Array();

for(var it in msgs)
{
    var langId = msgs[it]['langId'];
    langSectState[langId] = msgs[it]['bShow'];
}

for(var it in langSectState)
{
    console.log(it+":"+langSectState[it]);
}

</script>
```

Please note that console.log loop is added just for test purposes

Comment: Hi Mikali, Thanks for the code and Partially it solved my problem. The langId won't be duplicate. Its my mistake. But, the var msgs will have "=" sign instead of ":". Since it will be processed in jsp, I can't change the structure to ":" in Java code.